# I compiled code in IntelliJ and java could not find or load main class... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I have a basic print program made in IntelliJ, runs handy dandy in the intelliJ terminal but the minute I use cmd I get an error.
The `src` file has been compiled by IntelliJ already and the `Main.class` file is in the `out/bin` folder.
Noticed this problem for all my stuff in IntelliJ, granted I never needed to run anything in `cmd` before...

For reference here is my directory --> C:\Users...\IdeaProjects\JavaProjectFolder\out\production\JavaProjectFolder\com\Example\Main.class

The simple program I'm trying to run...

```
package com.Example;

public class Main
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Help me pls...");
}
}
```

I may have overlooked something here, but I'm a complete noob, so I can't really help it. Thanks to anyone who took time off their hands to help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this on your project root directory?

```sh
# try this on 'C:\Users...\IdeaProjects\JavaProjectFolder'
$ java -cp out\production\JavaProjectFolder com.Example.Main
Help me pls...
```